# How to make view center align, without lapping other view [constraintlayout only]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want my textView to be center align to screen and also don't want it to overlap the image. Can you please help me achieve this using constraint.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/merge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/iv_close"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/paa_action_bar_back_margin"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/vc_nav_bar_back" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
      style="@style/db_title_4.semibold"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@{title}"
      android:textColor="@color/shade_grease"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(title) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_close"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
      tools:visibility="visible" />


  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use guidelines inside the constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margins, as for marginTop, marginBottom, marginLeft, marginRight.
For example:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
  style="@style/db_title_4.semibold"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@{title}"
  android:textColor="@color/shade_grease"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(title) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_close"

  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

  tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
  tools:visibility="visible" />
```

You can configure the different margin values and make it fit your requirements. Or you can even remove some margins. In the end, it depends on you and your design.

**Edit:** As a reminder constraint layout works in a relative kind of manner. One object depends on the other, so make sure that your lines/guidelines are correct (in the .xml labeled as constraint_toStartOf, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Text will never overlap with the Image and Image will be aligned to the start.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/merge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/paa_action_bar_back_margin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vc_nav_bar_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
        style="@style/db_title_4.semibold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{title}"
        android:textColor="@color/shade_grease"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(title) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_close"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_close"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to constrain your text view to your image and give it `android:layout_width="0dp"` so it will only expand according to the space available.

Because his new width is not `wrap_content` your text view will not overlap the image and that's why he will only expand according to his constraints.

**So you need to do something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="some very long txtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasda"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_close"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_close" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want your text view to be exactly the same height as the image view add `android:layout_height="0dp"`, now when you will have a long text it will get scrollable and will not expand vertically.

**It will look like this:**

[image]

---

**Edit according to comment:**

**You can use your layout like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="some very long txtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasda"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_close"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**In order to get this look:**

[image]

**Or you can use this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_actionbar_page_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="some very long txtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasdatxtsadasdasdasdasdasda"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**In order to get this look:**

[image]

Comment: I want text view to be center of the screen, without overlapping imageview, this is only setting its center to available space.

Comment: So do you want your text to be below the image and not overlap it? is that correct?

Comment: I edited my answer - it this was not helping add image o how you want your layout to look so I can better understand it.